# iterate through dataframe and dictionary to update values in dataframe for matching strings with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {"name1":["name1_a, "name1_b"], "name2":["name2_a", "name2_b", "name2_c"]
```

Then I read in a .csv file as a dataframe that has the following structure:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| "name1" | 10 |
| "name1_b" | 30 |
| "name2_c" | 30 |

I need a function to iterate through the dataframe and the dictionary, in a way that it searches the dataframe for each name in the dictionary lists ("name1_a", "name1_b", etc). Once it finds a match, let's say for "name1_b", it should add the corresponding value (30) to "name1" in the dataframe. If the name doesn't exist in the dataframe (like "name2" in the example), it should create a new row and assign the value corresponding to the sum of "name2_a" + "name2_b", etc.

So the resulting dataframe should be like this (value of "name_1b" was added to the value of "name1", and "name2" was created and assigned the value of "name2_c):

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| "name1" | 40 |
| "name1_b" | 30 |
| "name2_c" | 30 |
| "name2" | 30 |

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you write this as a working example... at least the dict and dataframe initialization. We should be able to copy/paste to work on a solution.

Comment: Are names unique? Could, say, "name1" appear multiple times in the Name column?

Comment: yes names are unique in the dataframe

Comment: There is no "name2_a" in the dataframe, so I can't _assign the value corresponding to the sum of "name2_a" + "name2_b"_. Considering a name:list_of_names pair in `dict`, it seems like you want to add the values of the list_of_names to name, with a non-existent name defaulting to 0.

Comment: yes @tdelaney i think your interpretation is correct, since only "name2_c" is on the dataframe, the functions has to create a new row for "name" and assign it the value of "name2_c"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try firstly via dict comprehension make a key:value pair  out of the list then chack if 'Name' present in `dd` and filter out results then replace the values of 'Name' with their values by using `replace()` and `assign()` to assign the changes back then append this new dataframe in the original one and then groupby 'Name' and calculate sum:

```
d={"name1":["name1_a", "name1_b"], "name2":["name2_a", "name2_b", "name2_c"]}
dd={i:k for k,v in d.items() for i in v}
df=(df.append(df[df['Name'].isin(dd)]
      .assign(Name=lambda x:x['Name'].replace(dd)))
      .groupby('Name',as_index=False).sum())
```

OR

The same approach but in seperate steps:

```
d={"name1":["name1_a", "name1_b"], "name2":["name2_a", "name2_b", "name2_c"]}
dd={i:k for k,v in d.items() for i in v}
df1=df[df['Name'].isin(dd)]
df1['Name']=df1['Name'].map(dd)
df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
df=df.groupby('Name',as_index=False)['name2'].sum()
```

output of `df`:

```
    Name        name2
0   name1       40
1   name1_b     30
2   name2       30
3   name2_c     30
```

**Note:** don't assign anything to `dict` function in python

Answer (score 1):

You could index `df` by name and create a separate dataframe that holds values that will be added to df. Some target keys in `dict` won't be in `df`, so they will need to be added with a default. Its similar with the addend lists in `dict`, some will not have values and will need a default.

Once those two are setup, you can loop through the addends, collect sums and add those to `df`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["name1", "name1_b", "name2_c"],
    "Value":[10, 30, 30]})

# map of target:addends to apply to dataframe
mydict = {"name1":["name1_a", "name1_b"], "name2":["name2_a", "name2_b", "name2_c"]}

# index dataframe by name and default unknown values
df.set_index("Name", inplace=True)
unknowns = pd.DataFrame(index=mydict.keys()-df.index)
unknowns["Value"] = 0
df = df.append(unknowns)
del unknowns

# create dataframe addends, defaulting unknown values
addends_df = pd.DataFrame(index={val for values in mydict.values() 
        for val in values})
addends_df["Value"] = df
addends_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# for each target, add the addends
for target, addends in mydict.items():
    df.loc[target] += addends_df.loc[addends].sum()

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations! it worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the dictionary items and mask the data frame from the matching key and value list and get the sum value using .sum(). if a specific name exists in the data frame simply assign the value else create a new row.

```
dict_ = {"name1":["name1_a", "name1_b"], "name2":["name2_a", "name2_b", "name2_c"]}

for k,v in dict_.items():
    mask_list = v + [k]
    sum_value = df[df['Name'].isin(mask_list)]['Value'].sum()

    if k in df['Name'].unique():
        df.loc[df['Name'] == k, 'Value'] = sum_value
    else:
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [k, sum_value]
```